# Проблемы с установкой Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Не могу установить Jupiter. В консоли получаю следующую ошибку:

```
 Running setup.py install for pyzmq ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\486B~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t2v0v6bn\\pyzmq\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\486B~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t2v0v6bn\\pyzmq\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6b_gpdsr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Include\pyzmq'
     cwd: C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t2v0v6bn\pyzmq\
Complete output (198 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
Generating grammar tables from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\lib2to3\Grammar.txt
Writing grammar tables to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\lib2to3\Grammar3.7.6.final.0.pickle
Writing failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\lib2to3\\Grammar3.7.6.final.0.pickle'
Generating grammar tables from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\lib2to3\PatternGrammar.txt
Writing grammar tables to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\lib2to3\PatternGrammar3.7.6.final.0.pickle
Writing failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\lib2to3\\PatternGrammar3.7.6.final.0.pickle'
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq
copying zmq\decorators.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq
copying zmq\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq
copying zmq\_future.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq
copying zmq\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\asyncio
copying zmq\asyncio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\asyncio
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\auth
copying zmq\auth\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\auth
copying zmq\auth\certs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\auth
copying zmq\auth\ioloop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\auth
copying zmq\auth\thread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\auth
copying zmq\auth\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\auth
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\auth\asyncio
copying zmq\auth\asyncio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\auth\asyncio
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend
copying zmq\backend\select.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend
copying zmq\backend\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\context.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\devices.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\message.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\socket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\_cffi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\_poll.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
copying zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\devices
copying zmq\devices\basedevice.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\devices
copying zmq\devices\monitoredqueue.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\devices
copying zmq\devices\monitoredqueuedevice.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\devices
copying zmq\devices\proxydevice.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\devices
copying zmq\devices\proxysteerabledevice.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\devices
copying zmq\devices\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\devices
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop
copying zmq\eventloop\future.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop
copying zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop
copying zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop
copying zmq\eventloop\_deprecated.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop
copying zmq\eventloop\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\concurrent.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\ioloop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\stack_context.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform\auto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform\interface.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform\windows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform
copying zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\green
copying zmq\green\core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\green
copying zmq\green\device.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\green
copying zmq\green\poll.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\green
copying zmq\green\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\green
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\green\eventloop
copying zmq\green\eventloop\ioloop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\green\eventloop
copying zmq\green\eventloop\zmqstream.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\green\eventloop
copying zmq\green\eventloop\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\green\eventloop
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\log
copying zmq\log\handlers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\log
copying zmq\log\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\log
copying zmq\log\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\log
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\ssh
copying zmq\ssh\forward.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\ssh
copying zmq\ssh\tunnel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\ssh
copying zmq\ssh\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\ssh
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\attrsettr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\context.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\frame.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\poll.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\socket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\stopwatch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\tracker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
copying zmq\sugar\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\sugar
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_auth.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_cffi_backend.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_context.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_cython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_decorators.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_device.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_draft.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_etc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_future.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_imports.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_includes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_ioloop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_message.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_monitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_monqueue.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_multipart.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_pair.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_poll.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_proxy_steerable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_pubsub.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_reqrep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_retry_eintr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_security.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_socket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_ssh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_win32_shim.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_z85.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\test_zmqstream.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
copying zmq\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests\asyncio
copying zmq\tests\asyncio\test_asyncio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests\asyncio
copying zmq\tests\asyncio\_test_asyncio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests\asyncio
copying zmq\tests\asyncio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\tests\asyncio
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\constant_names.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\garbage.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\interop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\jsonapi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\monitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\strtypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\win32.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\z85.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq
copying zmq\backend\cffi\_cdefs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cffi\_verify.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cffi
copying zmq\backend\cython\checkrc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
copying zmq\backend\cython\context.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
copying zmq\backend\cython\libzmq.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
copying zmq\backend\cython\message.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
copying zmq\backend\cython\socket.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
copying zmq\backend\cython\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
copying zmq\backend\cython\constants.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
copying zmq\backend\cython\constant_enums.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\backend\cython
copying zmq\devices\monitoredqueue.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\devices
copying zmq\utils\buffers.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\getpid_compat.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\ipcmaxlen.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\mutex.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\pyversion_compat.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\zmq_compat.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
copying zmq\utils\zmq_constants.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\zmq\utils
running build_ext
running configure
{'libraries': ['libzmq'], 'include_dirs': [], 'library_dirs': [], 'runtime_library_dirs': [], 'extra_link_args': []}
Warning: Couldn't find an acceptable libzmq on the system.

If you expected pyzmq to link against an installed libzmq, please check to make sure:

    * You have a C compiler installed
    * A development version of Python is installed (including headers)
    * A development version of ZMQ >= 3.2 is installed (including headers)
    * If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
    * If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,
      try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
      or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`

You can skip all this detection/waiting nonsense if you know
you want pyzmq to bundle libzmq as an extension by passing:

    `--zmq=bundled`

I will now try to build libzmq as a Python extension
unless you interrupt me (^C) in the next 10 seconds...

************************************************
 1...
Using bundled libzmq
already have bundled\zeromq
staging platform.hpp from: C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t2v0v6bn\pyzmq\buildutils\include_win32
************************************************
************************************************
building 'zmq.libzmq' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t2v0v6bn\pyzmq\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t2v0v6bn\pyzmq\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6b_gpdsr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Include\pyzmq' Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перед установкой jupyter обновить следующие библиотеки и сам pip. Должно решить проблему. Запустите в консоли:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

А точнее тут важно обновить именно setuptools.

Comment: Установил, спасибо, но теперь не работает команда jupyter notebook. Выдаёт : " "jupyter" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."

Comment: Команда jupyter-notebook для запуска.

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его галочкой, как принятый.